# how to import a folder full of xml file into a datagridview and make them clickable file to read Apré in another datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, xml-parsing

i want's to know how to import one folder to a datagridview
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

```
        ofd.Filter = "XML Files (*.xml)|*.xml";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog()==System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {

            string filename = ofd.FileName;

        }

        textBox4.Text = ofd.FileName;

        if (textBox4.Text==ofd.FileName)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(ofd.FileName);
            richTextBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;
        }
```

Comment: you may want to use folderbrowserdialog instead.

Comment: can you please send me an example of using this folderbrowserdialog and specialy how to make it clickable on the datagridview